# How to put AmCharts chart in a slider in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, slider, amcharts

Are there any ways to embed an Amcharts chart into a slider on Wordpress? I have looked around and all seem to only allow images in the slider. I would like to just have a slider that instead of using images it uses charts from Amcharts that I have created.

Comment: There are a lot of WP sliders that allow HTML content. Which ones did you try? You should probably look for one that supports shortcodes, so that you can add amCahrts shortcode to the content of the slide.

Comment: Hmmm maybe I'm googling the wrong thing then. Can you name a few that support what I want to be done? thanks for the reply

Comment: Looks like you already got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the WP Anything Slider plugin!